# Testing with Mocha and trying to use babel and trying to use array.prototype.includes

Tags: mocha.js, webpack, babeljs

I am testing my react/redux code with Mocha and expect, I got mocha configured to use es6 , but it seems to lack support for the array.prototype.includes even when I have a .babelrc specifying stage-0. And in my non-test code, array.prototype.includes works. Are there some settings aside from babelrc specific to mocha that need to be set in order to use array.prototype.includes?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "expect": "^1.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.8.1",
    "cuid": "^1.3.8",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.1",
    "ramda": "^0.19.1",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-redux": "^2.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.1.7",
    "redux-crud": "^0.10.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.2",
    "redux-loop": "^1.0.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.4.1",
    "redux-simple-router": "^2.0.3",
    "reselect": "^2.0.3",
    "seamless-immutable": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.includes` is provided via `babel-polyfill` since it does not require transpiling. It looks like you already have `babel-polyfill` in your `package.json` so just make sure you are `import`ing it in your mocha tests.